# Word wrapping some text to not occupy empty space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this card

```
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
      <div class="ct">
        Health & safety
      </div>
   <div class="facetHolder mt-3">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="checkbox" /><span class="ml-3 dtext">Properties with additional health & safety measures</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <span class="badge badge-primary float-right">10</span>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dzfo41rk/5/

This is how it looks

[image: facet image]

The text on the right moves too much to the left and occupies the empty space not occupied by the checkbox.

I tried setting the whitespace

```
.dtext{
font-size:14px !important;
 white-space:normal !important;
    word-wrap: normal !important; 
}
```

but that is not helping. How can i ensure the text do not overflow to the left to occupy space around the checkbox?

Comment: why don't you put the checkbox in its own column?

Comment: Side note, you really should be using a label.

Comment: I added a label https://imgur.com/pm798Ob  to <input type="checkbox" /><span class="ml-3 dtext"><label>Properties with additional health & safety measures</label></span>

Comment: I added columns and worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Gandalf Bootstrap has `.form-check` class, a single class for both checkbox and radio input types that improves the layout and behavior of their HTML elements. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `label` instead of `span`
2. Wrap both `label` and the `input` with another element.
3. Use `.form-check`

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label ml-3 dtext" for="exampleCheck1">
    Properties with additional health & safety measures
  </label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/odr04tsj/

---

For more info, read **Checkboxes and radios**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the property `white-space: nowrap;` on any text containers. This will prevent the line breaks & force the text to one line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your text and checkbox in different columns of row. As now, checkbox with inline-block style looks like a part of text.
Other problem is big paddings of columns. Create them smaller with p-classes or change them with your stylesheets.
And the third thing, as epascarello said, you need labels for the checkboxes.

```
<div class="col-md-3 px-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="stackCheck"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 px-1">
  <label for="stackCheck" class="dtext">
    Properties with additional health & safety measures
  </label>
</div>
```

Look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lfbmj6t/1/

And please, don't use !important without necessary.